# Over Clause getting syntax errors in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

As got the answer from [How to combine two sql queries to get a one table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078472/how-to-combine-two-sql-queries-to-get-a-one-table-in-mysql) here I have a database as follows and I need the output as below.

```
Time         Number  Updated
2/10/2022 10:12 12345     1    
2/11/2022 10:12 234       0    
2/12/2022 10:12 433       0    
2/13/2022 10:12 556       0    
2/14/2022 10:12 4357      0    
2/15/2022 10:12 12345     0
```

output:

```
Time            Number  Updated    Last Updated
2/10/2022 10:12 12345     1      2/15/2022 10:12
2/11/2022 10:12 234       0      2/11/2022 10:12
2/12/2022 10:12 433       0      2/12/2022 10:12
2/13/2022 10:12 556       0      2/13/2022 10:12
2/14/2022 10:12 4357      0      2/14/2022 10:12
2/15/2022 10:12 12345     0      2/15/2022 10:12
```

We can get the output by using following query,

```
SELECT
    Time,
    Number,
    MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Number) AS LastUpdated
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Time;
```

This works fine when I have used it in my localhost with php file. But when I am using this same query in my remote server I am getting syntax error as,

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by....
```

Seems my mysql version in remote server(`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73`) doesn't support that. Can someone provide alternative way to do this same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version didn't support `window function`, You can try to use subquery with `MAX` to make it.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    Time,
    Number,
    (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM yourTable tt WHERE t.Number = tt.Number) LastUpdated
FROM yourTable t
ORDER BY Time;
```

or use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` to get the lastest each `Number`

```
SELECT
    Time,
    Number,
    (SELECT Time FROM yourTable tt WHERE t.Number = tt.Number ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1) LastUpdated
FROM yourTable t
ORDER BY Time;
```

| Time | Number | LastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-10 10:12:00 | 12345 | 2022-02-15 10:12:00 |
| 2022-02-11 10:12:00 | 234 | 2022-02-11 10:12:00 |
| 2022-02-12 10:12:00 | 433 | 2022-02-12 10:12:00 |
| 2022-02-13 10:12:00 | 556 | 2022-02-13 10:12:00 |
| 2022-02-14 10:12:00 | 4357 | 2022-02-14 10:12:00 |
| 2022-02-15 10:12:00 | 12345 | 2022-02-15 10:12:00 |

Comment: what mean by tt.Number?

Comment: `tt.Number` is the value from the subquery which want to get each `Number` `Max` of Time

Comment: are there any efficient way to do this?It tis taking more time. I have thousands of records.

Comment: You need to create a suitable index for your table  you can try to use `CREATE INDEX ix_yourtable_number ON  yourtable (NUMBER,Time);`

Comment: without modifying anything in the table, are there anything to do?